# In my Blazor server side app I get security Error when I try to use the material fonts of google. Why?

Tags: css, url, icons, blazor-server-side

In my Blazor server side app, I want to use the material icons of google. Therefore I have added following reference in the head part of my _host.cshtml file. Normally the css link was a link in the internet.

```
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Icons+Outlined"
  rel="stylesheet">
```

But as my server has no internet acces I have downloaded the css and have put it into the wwwroot/css directory.

```
<link href="css/material_fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

In the css file there was an url in the src: parameter like

src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialiconsoutlined/v109/gok-H7zzDkdnRel8-DQ6KAXJ69wP1tGnf4ZGhUce.woff2) format('woff2');

I have downloaded the file due to the same reason and put it also into the wwwroot/css folder. So I changed the src: parameter like below:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Material Icons Outlined';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: url(file:///css/gok-H7zzDkdnRel8-DQ6KAXJ69wP1tGnf4ZGhUce.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons-outlined {
font-family: 'Material Icons Outlined';
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 1;
letter-spacing: normal;
text-transform: none;
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap;
word-wrap: normal;
direction: ltr;
-moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

When I run my app I get in the browser inspect following error:

Security Error: Content at https://XXXXXXXXXXX:4444/CNC_Status may not load or link to file:///css/gok-H7zzDkdnRel8-DQ6KAXJ69wP1tGnf4ZGhUce.woff2.

downloadable font: failed to start download (font-family: "Material Icons Outlined" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: file:///css/gok-H7zzDkdnRel8-DQ6KAXJ69wP1tGnf4ZGhUce.woff2

What is wrong?